# How to run in parallel several docker services on a docker-compose file and then check for the global status code?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, health-check

I need to test a python application on different environments (different python versions, different pip packages) with pytest. For that, I created a Dockerfile which accepts different build arguments, and fill those args from a docker compose template, like this:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  python37:
    image: py3.7.0
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        PYTHON_VER: "3.7.0"
        PIP_VER: "19.0.3"
        NUMPY_VER: "1.17.5"
        PANDAS_VER: "0.24.0"
        SKLEARN_VER: "0.19.2"
  python38:
    image: py3.8.0
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        PYTHON_VER: "3.8.0"
        PIP_VER: "20.3.2"
        NUMPY_VER: "1.20.0"
        PANDAS_VER: "1.0.0"
        SKLEARN_VER: "0.24.2"
  python310:
    image: py3.10.0
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        PYTHON_VER: "3.10.0"
        PIP_VER: "22.3.1"
        NUMPY_VER: "1.24.0"
        PANDAS_VER: "1.5.2"
        SKLEARN_VER: "1.2.0"
```

The CMD in the Dockerfile just calls pytest over some test I've defined.
What I want is to run all services, as in `docker-compose up` but in a way that if any of the services fails its tests, then the whole execution should also fail.

I've tried `docker-compose up --exit-code-from` but this only works for a particular service and I want to check the global exit code

Also tried `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit` but the returning code of this is seems to be always 0.

How can I achieve that?